# How can I make a search form working with "Name Surname"

Tags: python, django, search

Basically the issue is that at the moment my search bar is working if I search the exact "Name" or the exact "Surname", however, I would like it to work also if a user searches "Name Surname" or even if the user misspells the name or the surname but at least one of the two is correct.

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get("q", None)
    qs = DeathAd.objects.all()
    if query is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(
            Q(nome__icontains=query) |
            Q(cognome__icontains=query)
        )
    context = {
        "object_list": qs,
    }
    template = "search.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the queryset with the [**`Concat`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) of the `name`, a space and the `cogname`:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

qs = qs.annotate(
    full_name=Concat('nome', Value(' '), 'cognome')
).filter(
    Q(nome__icontains=query) |
    Q(cognome__icontains=query) |
    Q(full_name__icontains=query)
)
```

> (…) or even if the user misspells the name or the surname but at least one of the two is correct.

For this you will need more advanced search technology, like an *Elasticsearch* backend, and you can make use of [**`django-haystack`** [readthedocs]](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to talk with these backends.

Comment: Thank you Sir, your solution seems to work very well and your guess has been insightful

Comment: Any suggestion in order to add the paginator to this view?

Answer (score 0):

maybe do some python in there. Why not split the query with ' ' a dash, separating name and surname into a list. Then creating an empty list to append to. Like this,

```
def search(request):
query = request.GET.get("q", None).split(' ')
q_list = []
if query is not None:
    for qs in query:
    result = DeathAd.objects.filter(qs)
    q_list.append(result)
context = {
    "object_list": q_list,
}
template = "search.html"
return render(request, template, context)
```

If you want, you can use sets in case there are dublicate results